# Headless Chrome (Selenium) requests not being submitted/ working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open a bulk of URLs from two CSV files in headless chrome using Selenium. The code runs fine but upon checking wireshark, there is no traffic going through. Below is the code which I believe should be functioning properly but it's not, perhaps I skipped a step?

```py
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Read the CSV files with encoding
top_domains_df = pd.read_csv('Top1MillionDomians.csv', encoding='utf-8', dtype=str)
malware_urls_df = pd.read_csv('Malurl.csv', encoding='utf-8', dtype=str)

# Get the first column from each DataFrame
top_domains = top_domains_df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
malware_urls = malware_urls_df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()

# Initialize Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
###chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
##chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

chrome_options.headless = True

# Function to process a URL
def process_url(url):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)  # Maximum 15 seconds per URL
        driver.get(url)
        # Add your processing logic here
        driver.quit()
        return url, True
    except:
        driver.quit()
        return url, False

def perform_request(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        return url, response.status_code == 200
    except:
        return url, False

def process_with_progress(url, pbar):
    result = perform_request(url)
    update_progress_bar(result, pbar)
    return result

def update_progress_bar(result, pbar):
    url, success = result
    if success:
        pbar.set_description(f"Processing: {url} (Success)")
    else:
        pbar.set_description(f"Processing: {url} (Error)")
    pbar.update(1)
    print(f"Processed URL: {url} (Success: {success})")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    batch_size = 500
    num_processes = 4  # Number of parallel processes
    
    with tqdm(total=len(malware_urls), desc="Processing URLs") as pbar:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_processes) as executor:
            futures = []
            for url in malware_urls:
                future = executor.submit(process_with_progress, url, pbar)
                futures.append(future)
            
            for future in futures:
                future.result()
    
    print("All URLs processed.")
```

I tried using the same dataset using pycurl and it works fine so could it be other factors such as the platform I'm using (Kali Linux). I have also tried switching between Firefox and chrome webdrivers as well as alternating between the commented options but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the source of the problem: SCHEMA. I just needed to write the second line of def perform_request(url): like this

```
response = requests.get("http://" + url, timeout=5)
```